# How is the version defined from a web application by jboss 5 in the admin console

Tags: web-applications, jboss, war, jboss5.x

in the JBoss AS Administration Console - if you select a web application, you see some information like the name of the application. There is also the property 'Version' - but in not one application it is filled. I did not find anything useful in the JBoss guide, how this information has to be provided by the war file. So my question is...does anyone know how to provide the information?

The JBoss Version I am using is JBoss 5.1.0GA

Here is a sceenshot of what I mean:
[image: a busy cat]

Many thanks :)